# Windows 2003 Shadow copy

Tags: windows-server-2003, vss

Is it possible to enable shadow copy for a single folder, not an entire volume? I know this is possible in server 2008, but I cannot locate similar options in 2003. If this is possible how do I go about enabling it and restoring previous versions of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word no. With server 2003 shadow copy is on a per volume only basis.

Comment: At first look that seemed to be the case, but I figured they may be some sort of creative work around I haven't thought of. Thanks